# Cannot launch AVD in emulator: hax_slot_insert

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know others have similar questions, but my problem is a little different.

When I try launching my AVD I almost immediately receive a popup saying that "qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working". When I exit the popup, I receive a message which says:

> "Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>   Output:
>   Hax is enabled
>   Hax ram_size 0x100000000
>   HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
>   hax_slot_insert: Failed to set memory mapping (err=-14)
>   This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information."

I don't know what to do.

If it helps, I am emulating a Nexus 6P running Lollipop 5.1 x86 (with Google APIs). I set the machine to 4GB RAM, 786MB VM heap, and 4GB Internal Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Useful Note :**

> If you are specifying `1024 MB RAM` then you have to specify the
>   device screen size is `hdpi` only and if it is `512 MB RAM` then it
>   should be `mdpi` or other.

**Conclusion :**

From the above note we have clearly say that `RAM Size` should be specify according to the screen size. if you are specified the `1024 MB RAM` size while keeping the device screen size is `mdpi`. then it results should be above mention error.

Comment: What I did to resolve this problem was just leave the RAM settings alone. The emulator worked fine after that.

Comment: @NathanB glad to help you.